# Install Colorls on macOS and zsh

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command, anaconda

I want to install Colorls. I am completely new to Ruby. To install Colorls I executed:

```
gem install colorls --user-install
```

After I while (maybe after I installed Anaconda) Colorls is not working anymore. 
*zsh: command not found: colorls*

Here's some info:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.1 (2019-01-30 patchlevel 33) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/matteo/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/matteo/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/matteo/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/matteo/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/matteo/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible your ruby version doesn't match gem version?  Seems like minor version in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
```

Make sure you still have the gem installed:

```
which colorls

#should output something like:  /Users/yourusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/colorls
```

See if the gem is indeed installed

```
gem list colorls
```

Then maybe try reinstall see https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls#install

You might wanna use a version manager, I recommend RVM see https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: which colorls --> colorls not found

Comment: gem list colorls -->  *** LOCAL GEMS *** (empty?)

Comment: did you try `gem install colorls` ?

Comment: try `gem uninstall colorls` and then `gem install colorls`

Answer (score 2):

I always forget how to install **colorls** when I reformat my Mac.
I have:

- macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 (don't miss with the preinstalled ruby)

I follow these steps:

### Step -1-

Install ruby using homebrew

```sh
brew install ruby
```

### Step -2-

Go to the directory

```sh
cd /usr/local/Celler/ruby/<x.x.x>/bin
# Or for ARM Mac I use here 3.1.1 that comes with brew install ruby
cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/bin
# Then 
./gem install colorls
```

my version is (3.0.1)

### Step -3-

Now you are ready to link this library to the default one you installed before (following the GitHub repo steps of the colorls)

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/x.x.x/bin/colorls /usr/local/bin/colorls

# or for ARM Mac I use here gem 3.1.0
ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/colorls /usr/local/bin/colorls
```

Hint: if you find any other colorls in the directory prior to executing the link command just remove it.
now check:

[image]